# Pictures in Infopath 2013 Form not being display in email

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have an Infopath 2013 form that has a picture field. The form is set up to submit to email and sharepoint document library. When a user uploads a picture to this form and when the form submits, the picture does not display in an email but it does when you open up the form in the sharepoint library.

Does anyone know how to upload a picture into a Infopath form then have it appear in email?

Thanks